# EKS - Pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims on t2.large instances (t2.large, Bottlerocket OS)

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

i've looked through several solutions but couldnt find an answer, so i'm trying to run a stateful set on the cluster, but the pod fails to run because of unbound claim. I'm running **t2.large** machines with **Bottlerocket** host types.

**kubectl get events**

```
28m         Warning   FailedScheduling         pod/carabbitmq-0                              pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims (repeated 3 times)
28m         Normal    Scheduled                pod/carabbitmq-0                              Successfully assigned default/carabbitmq-0 to ip-x.compute.internal
28m         Normal    SuccessfulAttachVolume   pod/carabbitmq-0                              AttachVolume.Attach succeeded for volume "pvc-f6e8ec20-4bc1-4539-8d11-2dd1b3dbd4d7"
28m         Normal    Pulled                   pod/carabbitmq-0                              Container image "busybox:1.30.1" already present on machine
```

**kubectl get pv,pvc** + describe

```
NAME                                      STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
persistentvolumeclaim/data-carabbitmq-0   Bound    pvc-f6e8ec20-4bc1-4539-8d11-2dd1b3dbd4d7   30Gi       RWO            gp2            12m

NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                        STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/pvc-f6e8ec20-4bc1-4539-8d11-2dd1b3dbd4d7   30Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound    rabbitmq/data-carabbitmq-0   gp2                     12m
```

describe pv:

```
Name:              pvc-f6e8ec20-4bc1-4539-8d11-2dd1b3dbd4d7
Labels:            failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region=eu-west-1
                   failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone=eu-west-1b
Annotations:       kubernetes.io/createdby: aws-ebs-dynamic-provisioner
                   pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
                   pv.kubernetes.io/provisioned-by: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:        [kubernetes.io/pv-protection]
StorageClass:      gp2
Status:            Bound
Claim:             rabbitmq/data-carabbitmq-0
Reclaim Policy:    Retain
Access Modes:      RWO
VolumeMode:        Filesystem
Capacity:          30Gi
Node Affinity:     
  Required Terms:  
    Term 0:        failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/zone in [eu-west-1b]
                   failure-domain.beta.kubernetes.io/region in [eu-west-1]
Message:           
Source:
    Type:       AWSElasticBlockStore (a Persistent Disk resource in AWS)
    VolumeID:   aws://eu-west-1b/vol-xx
    FSType:     ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false
Events:         <none>
```

describe pvc:

```
Name:          data-carabbitmq-0
Namespace:     rabbitmq
StorageClass:  gp2
Status:        Bound
Volume:        pvc-f6e8ec20-4bc1-4539-8d11-2dd1b3dbd4d7
Labels:        app=rabbitmq-ha
               release=rabbit-mq
Annotations:   pv.kubernetes.io/bind-completed: yes
               pv.kubernetes.io/bound-by-controller: yes
               volume.beta.kubernetes.io/storage-provisioner: kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Finalizers:    [kubernetes.io/pvc-protection]
Capacity:      30Gi
Access Modes:  RWO
VolumeMode:    Filesystem
Mounted By:    carabbitmq-0
Events:
  Type    Reason                 Age   From                         Message
  ----    ------                 ----  ----                         -------
  Normal  ProvisioningSucceeded  36m   persistentvolume-controller  Successfully provisioned volume pvc-f6e8ec20-4bc1-4539-8d11-2dd1b3dbd4d7 using kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
```

The storage type is gp2.

```
Name:                  gp2
IsDefaultClass:        Yes
Annotations:           storageclass.kubernetes.io/is-default-class=true
Provisioner:           kubernetes.io/aws-ebs
Parameters:            encrypted=true,type=gp2
AllowVolumeExpansion:  <unset>
MountOptions:
  debug
ReclaimPolicy:      Retain
VolumeBindingMode:  Immediate
Events:             <none>
```

I'm not sure what i'm missing, same configuration used to work until i switched to "t" type of EC2s

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the YAML specification for the StatefulSet that you're submitting to the cluster, and any other important details for a [mcve]?

Comment: I've actually found the issue - it looks like my readiness probe failed, which i thought is unrelated, but it caused this error. fixing the readiness probe made the problem disappear.

Comment: @ArielB can you provide your solution with description as an answer? It might help other users with similar issue.

Comment: Done, hope it helps someone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it was weird but i had some readiness probe that failed its healthchecks, i thought that it was because the volume was not mounted well.

The healthcheck basically did some request to localhost, which it had issues on (not sure why) - changing to 127.0.0.1 made the check pass, and then the volume error disappeard.

So - if you have this weird issue (volumes were mounted, but you still get that error) - check the pod's probes.